# How can I redirect users from a webpage or another webpage to a webpage

Tags: php, html, http, redirect, https

I need something like this

```
<?php
  if http://growtopiajaw.my.vg
  else if https://growtopiajaw.my.vg
  then
  header('Location: https://growtopiajaw.my.vg/homepage.html', true, 301);
  exit();
?>
```

Basiclly, if I type in the URL growtopiajaw.my.vg, it will automaticlly redirect to https://growtopiajaw.my.vg/homepage.html. But when I type in the URL https://growtopiajaw.my.vg, it will keep refreshing in an infinite loop.

I know that some people will try to access the https://growtopiajaw.my.vg page.

I don't want my site to be problematic for users. Also, you can try visiting the site https://www.growtopiajaw.my.vg. You can see that it keeps refreshing the page non-stop.

So, I am seeking help from anyone who can help me. Thank you!

> EDIT:

Okay, so my question is not quite clear. What I actually meant was something like this. Redirect http://growtopiajaw.my.vg and https://growtopiajaw.my.vg (if the user went to this URL) to a specific page on https which makes the link https://growtopiajaw.my.vg/homepage.html. I currently have the code below in http://growtopiajaw.my.vg/index.html.

`<?php
  header('Location: https://growtopiajaw.my.vg/homepage.html', true, 301);
  exit();
?>`

The server will automaticlly load the index.html so it will redirect to the page https:/growtopiajaw.my.vg/homepage.html. (I cannot post more than 8 links. sorry)

Comment: That's not valid PHP code.

Comment: @tadman lol... was just gonna say that

Comment: Please show what code you have so far

Comment: You can check `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` to determine if you're already being served via HTTPS.

Comment: when using `https` ensure you have a cert --- though that should have no bearing on the *infinite loop* issue, I am thinking...

Comment: So is your question how to redirect from http to https or is your question how to redirect from the root to a specific page?

Comment: If you want to redirect to https from http why don’t you do it at web server level?

Comment: Are you using any framework, or is it just vanilla PHP, HTML files?

Comment: @LelioFaieta My Cpanel doesn't have that option. sorry.

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks for pointing that out. I meant something like that. Added that to the question!

Comment: @Rushikumar I have a valid cert and I just renewed it yesterday. My Cpanel does't have the option to redirect to the https version. Because I'm using a free hosting with a subdomain. So the options in the Cpanel are obviously limited.

Comment: @TheSk8rJesus vanilla PHP. HTML files. No framework.

Comment: If no framework why not just rename homepage.html to index.html or do you need it named that for something in particular?

Comment: @TheSk8rJesus I used 2 pages because i need to redirect the http version to the https version with a specific page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there are two possible scenarios that may apply here...

#### Scenario 1 - Redirect all `HTTP` traffic to `HTTPS`

You can achieve this by simply adding an `.htaccess` to the root of your project with the following contents...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Notice the type of redirect here... it is `301` which translates to **permanent** redirect (vs. `302`, which translates to **temporary** redirection)

[Source: GoDaddy](https://www.godaddy.com/help/redirect-http-to-https-automatically-8828)

#### Scenario 2 - Redirect (only) the *landing page* to `HTTPS`

A landing page is basically `PAGE_NAME.EXT`. This can have many forms... for example, consider the following excerpt from a hosting provider--

> Our Web servers look for index files in this order:
>
> index.html index.htm index.shtml index.php index.php5 index.php4
>   index.php3 index.cgi default.html default.htm home.html home.htm
>   Index.html Index.htm Index.shtml Index.php Index.cgi Default.html
>   Default.htm Home.html Home.htm placeholder.html
>
> If the top level of
>   your website contains a file with any of those names, that file will
>   be shown when visitors don't specify a file name.

[Source: TigerTech](https://support.tigertech.net/index-file-names)

For simplicity sake, let's say your **default** landing page is `index.html`.

In which case, simply create `index.html` in the root of your project and add the following--

```
<?php
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: https://growtopiajaw.my.vg/homepage.html");
    exit();
?>
```

Now, any attempts to load `//growtopiajaw.my.vg` should take the user to `https://growtopiajaw.my.vg/homepage.html`

Notice though, this will redirect ONLY IF the user enters the `growtopiajaw.my.vg` URL --- if they go to `growtopiajaw.my.vg/about.html` then it will undoubtedly take them to a `HTTP` version of such a page.

Comment: My website is redirecting fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Place a php file named `index.php` in your root directory. Write your code in it.

```
<?php
  header('Location: https://growtopiajaw.my.vg/homepage.html');
  exit;
```

Now all requests to `http://growtopiajaw.my.vg` and `https://growtopiajaw.my.vg` will be redirected to `https://growtopiajaw.my.vg/homepage.html`

Comment: Not quite what I wanted. Sorry.

Comment: Check the answer now

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you rename homepage.html to index.php and then add the following code above the `doctype` tag

```
<?php
    if( !isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
        header( "location: https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]" );
        exit();
    }
?>
```

This is all based on not being able to setup 301 rules on the server itself. Otherwise use what  @Rushikumar has suggested.